# oracle/sql insert dd.mmm value into date column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-format

had to make a table in oracle aplication express with this cmd

```
create table predari
(
numar number(4), 
data date, 
cantitate number(4,2), 
cod_pdr number(2)
)
```

the way it should look in the table would be this format -> **20.oct** <-
but when i try to insert values with this cmd

```
insert into predari values(100, 20.oct , 50, 60) 
--i get error of missing commas

insert into predari values(100, '20.oct' , 50, 60)
--i get *ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

insert into predari values(100, '20.october' , 50, 60)
--i get *ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

so the format i need would be **dd.mmm** but i dont know where the problem lies, any help please?

EDIT: p.s. i want to insert the values in that fashion not to get them showed with select in that format, if i do select * from table i want it to appear as 20.oct

Comment: do you use mysql or oracle?

Comment: hmm my bad i forgot to mention..i;m pretty sure it's oracle

Comment: did you try `to_date('20.Oct','dd.mon')`? When you do select * from table, client will display date in the format you set in properties or DB NLS settings. To show date column in the format you want you need to change format in your select or store date as VARCHAR

Comment: what i;m looking for is to be able to INSERT values in the table, but the date column values give me errors, i want to know how to enter the value so it would appear as 20.oct (or just any value in that format)

Answer (score 0):

When inserting a string literal to a `date` column you are in fact performing an implicit type conversion, which relies on the database's default date format.

Even if it would work, this is a bad practice, as it couples your code to a specific configuration and makes it less portable. Instead, you should **explicitly** state the date format you want to use, e.g., by using the [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function:

```
INSERT INTO predari VALUE (100, TO_DATE('20.oct', 'dd.mon') , 50, 60)
```

Comment: did that and it inserted the values, but with select * from predari, the table shows it like this "20/Oct/2015" instead of '20.oct', any reason why? i have the table model made in excel with custom format cell of dd.mmm is that maybe why?

Comment: @Kibaro That's the default date format you seem to be using. The same formatting function (`to_date`) can (and should!) be used when you query the data.

Comment: i see thank you, last question for another table also on the date thing, the date needs to be "3.14.12 13:30" all i get is that it would look to_date('3.14.12 13:30', 'mm.dd.yy ????') idk what to put for the time part

Comment: @Kibaro use `hh24:mi` for ex: `to_date('3.14.12 13:30', 'mm.dd.yy hh24:mi')`

Comment: @Kibaro the last part would be an hour and minute specification - `TO_DATE('03.14.12 13:30', 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi')`

Comment: i did that, it inserted but again when i do select * from table it shows the date as 14/march/2012 with no time, is there a way to set a specific select format for each table so it would show exactly how i want with select * from table?